# Way to use Futures inside Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, spray

I need to perform thousands of tasks simultaneously. So i am thinking of using Futures for this purpose. But each of these thousands tasks are already in Future. Is it good to use future inside future. Or i am doing something wrong here.
Each task takes approx 1 ms time to compute. So instead of performing them sequentially i think it is preferable to do in futures. So theoretically it should take approx 1 ms or somewhere around that to complete entire task. But complete execution is taking 150 ms. So does that mean all parallel tasks are taking more than what it is taking individually.

```
val start = System.nanoTime()
```

Comment: Not only is it a good idea that is how it is supposed to be used. This is why `Future` is designed as a Monad. So we can compose and chain computations !  Do it !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flatMap()` function on futures to compose them, which I guess is what you call "futures inside futures", and it's a great idiomatic way to use futures.

Map express "with the result of this future, trigger this one". For example you could do something like `getASpecificEndpointInDb().flatMap(endpointURL => doAGetRequest(endpointURL))` where getASpecificEndpointInDb() returns a Future[String] and doAGetRequest() returns a Future[JsObject]

To answer the second part of your question : even if you have 1000 parallel tasks, your computer can only physically process a small number at any given time. Depending on your machine, if it's, let's say 8, the best it can achieve theorically is then 1000/8 = 125 ms. But as there are some context switching costs, 150ms is totally reasonable. And still a lot better than 1000ms if doing it sequentially :)

Comment: If you want to compose futures, you're more than likely to want to use `flatMap`, not `map`. Your example precisely call for using `flatMap`, using `map` is an error.